# Any confirmation on a Ryzen 5 2400 with Elementary OS?

Tags: kernel, hardware

I've seen a few older posts regarding this with nothing concrete, so I thought I'd ask.

I'm considering a Ryzen 5 2600 CPU (with the Asus Prime A32OM-K motherboard) and I noticed people have said you want kernel 4.17 to ensure your Linux OS is stable with a Ryzen CPU.

I noticed Elementary OS Loki is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which apparently is kernel 4.15.

Has anyone tried a Ryzen CPU with Elementary OS recently>  If there are issues, is it recommended to upgrade the kernel myself?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Pantheon Desktop on fedora 30. And it runs really great. My CPU is a AMD Ryzen 5 1600X (6 core). My Current kernel version is 5.1.8-300. I have used for a long time, maybe over 10 years, only ubuntu and manjaro. But Fedora 30 is really surprising me a lot. And I think to switch to fedora. The Pantheon desktop is running faster and smoother as like in Elementary OS 5.0. The Pantheon desktop is still not completely integrated, but for my requirements it's good enough.

Back to your question
My AMD Ryzen 5 1600X CPU is absolutely Elementary OS 5.0 an Fedora 30 (GNOME + Pantheon) compatible. Why should the a bigger CPU from AMD not be compatible?

Cheers Chris

Comment: "Why should a bigger CPU from AMD not be compatible?" Because everything I've read said that you need kernel 4.17 to ensure your Linux OS is stable with a Ryzen CPU.  Elementary OS Loki is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which apparently is kernel 4.15.  (All information given in the initial question - I just copied and pasted my sentences).

That's great it works with Fedora, in fact I'm not surprised, Fedora is known for being cutting edge. But my question was not about Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-t-series/ThinkPad-T14-AMD-G1/p/20UD0007US

and external monitors are not working. Tried POP OS - works ok